# Parsing text for email id's

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-match

I am trying to parse text for email id's using php / regex. Are there any classes or built in methods to do this?
The text contains multiple email id's at random places.

The source of the text is .doc files, which I then copy paste into forms, to be processed on submit.

```
preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email) //from php.net
```

I submitted a similar question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/191811/how-to-extract-email-ids-from-a-document-using-word-or-writer) for software solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to accurately detect emails embedded in running text. You will either match stuff that isn't an e-mail address erroneously, or miss some valid but strange e-mail addresses.

A good starting point is

```
preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

(generated by [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) from its library)

It will match most "normal" addresses ok, but won't find ones like `mail@1.2.3.4` or `"Tim\ O'Reilly"@microsoft.com`. And of course it will match nonsense like `my@mail.addr`.